# How do I choose an artifact from Nexus in a Hudson / Jenkins job?

Tags: hudson, nexus

I have a job in Hudson server A which builds an artifact and deploys it to Nexus. I have another job in a completely separate Hudson server B which needs to download the artifact and deploy it. This job is normally run manually, and the person running it needs to indicate which version of the artifact to deploy - they may not always want to deploy the latest version (e.g. to roll back to a previous known good version).

Currently, I achieve this by using a parameterized build, and require the user to pass in the artifact version number; the job then uses the *Execute shell* build step to run `wget` on a URL constructed using the parameter. This is error prone.

Ideally I'd like a plugin that lets the user browse the artifact versions in the Nexus repository and pick and choose the one to deploy, but I'm open to other suggestions. A plugin that also handles the download would be nice, but I can live without it as long as I can still get a string that I can use in shell commands.

I've looked through the available Hudson & Jenkins plugins around Maven style artifact repositories, but they all seem more concerned with pushing artifacts into repos rather than getting them back down.

I'm using Hudson's "Copy Artifact" in other jobs, to get artifacts from other Hudson jobs on the same server, but this doesn't work across different Hudson servers, which is why I've turned to Nexus (which we're already using anyway).

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using [rundeck](http://rundeck.org/) to execute your deployments.

- There is a [rundeck plugin for Nexus](https://github.com/vbehar/nexus-rundeck-plugin) that enables rundeck to display a pull down menu of available versions in Nexus.
- There is a [rundeck plugin for Jenkins](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/RunDeck+Plugin) that can be used to invoke deployments using rundeck and kick-off post deployment jobs (like integration testing) inn Jenkins.